# exception while using OuputStreamWriter

Tags: android, file, android-studio, directory, outputstream

when using OutputStreamWriter, while I try to make multiple directories (depending on a function result) and writing strings into the files, I have an exception.

Why does my program keep jumping to exception and saveFile() always return false?

```
 private boolean saveFile() {

    File card = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(card.getAbsolutePath() + choosePath());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();// creates directory by the given pathname
    }
    File file = new File(dir, etFileName.getText().toString());
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write(configString); // from character to byte
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to exec that code in debug so you can understand which line fails

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); // this line I think , I can't debug very good on emulator because I need my directories . I get a fatal crash but as far as I can do, when I click on save it returns a false and when I try to look at my file list it just crashes. and at this line it said in debugger null pointer exception which is weired tried debugging all morning to no result

Comment: is file null or not?

Comment: etFileName.getText() returns some value?

Comment: no I checked etFileName with a toast it returns whatever text I write in my text field like it should

Comment: It's not etFile I think it could be the File or I am using StremWriter wrong or the Directory dir can not be made... hence the empty file ... I am out of Ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 private boolean saveFile() {

    File card = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String fullPath = card.getAbsolutePath() 
        + choosePath()
        + etFileName.getText().toString(); //I guess this should generate the fullPath, if i understood well your code
    File file = new File(fullPath); //open the file
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); //create parent dirs if necessary
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write(configString); // from character to byte
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**: added "file.createNewFile()"

**EDIT 2**: be sure to have the right to write file. You should have this in you manifest file

Comment: unfortunately the very same problem still!!! good Idea, I played with mkdirs() for a while myself. but save file still returns false and does not save any new files into the directory

Comment: I have a Load file that works perfectly . that's what makes this so annoying!

Comment: which line of my answer fails? which variables ends up to be null?

Comment: File file = new File(fullPath); //open the file
this is ok I get file: .... not null! but yet, this line fails             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: as if file is not the correct parameter for FileOutPutStream! from here it jumps to exception, which is exactly how it worked with my code. I also tried a Bufferedwriter didn't get any better. though I confess I had no clue what I was doing just did the revese of Bufferedreader

Comment: I just wanted to also hint that fos is not created at all before it jumps.

Comment: file={File@4622}"/storage/emulated/0/MasterConfig/ListaPreciosabd" I'm starting to think there is sth wrong with the outputStreamWriter of my android version which is the newest one ... same error, same line, jumps from first line of try to exception

Comment: but are you sure you have the right to write files? you should have this in you manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `

Comment: errrm ... I did not think of that! I checked I don't have that in my manifest . just added this line I'll try my original code and let you know if this was the problem.

Comment: it works! you are my knight !!!! thank you very much ... how can I like give you points or upVotes in this forum?

Comment: @Heidi, I updated my answer, now should be 100% correct, please accept it and vote it, thanks :)